# How to automatically move different excel files from one folder to multiple folders using SharePoint

Tags: excel, file, sharepoint, task, multiple-users

In SharePoint i will receive multiple excel files every 30 minutes in a folder named assigned work ..I want to move the certain files to certain users  automatically
Is there a way to move files automatically in SharePoint

I searched and got to know that we need to use power automate to move the files ..can anyone guide me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.